# Are Suntour XCM30 forks adjustable with lockout?

Tags: fork, suspension, adjustment, lockout

I have a couple of issues I could do with some answers, I hope you don't mind me asking all in one go.

I have a Carrera 29er that came with Suntour XCM30 Forks, the store that sold it has the specifications listed as :

Adjustable - NO
Lockout - NO

After looking on the Suntour website I found what I think are the ones in question but they list them as :

Adjustable - Yes 
Lockout - Yes

Suntour Website [XCM](https://www.srsuntour.us/products/xcm32-lo-ds-15qlc32-650b-1?variant=33796680846)

So to keep this from getting too long :

1. Are my forks adjustable?
2. Can they be locked out?
3. If so, can it be done with a basic toolkit?

Attached pics of my front end and the spec sheet from the store the bike came from.

[Image 1](https://ibb.co/HTw83x6)
[Image 2](https://ibb.co/C035S6Z)
[Image 3](https://ibb.co/rs9kLJ5)
[Image 4](https://ibb.co/P4TDZFx)
[Image 5](https://ibb.co/YkWwPJB)

Comment: If I can see a shot of image 5 in better light I think I can answer your question. Also a shot of the other fork station from the top. I am interested in the (caps) for lack of a better word. On top of the forks. That's what will tell you if they are L O or not.

Comment: I am guessing these are hydraulic sprung forks? Not air sprung forks? Just to save me searching the spec.

Comment: From what specs I can find, I believe they're hydraulic sprung.

Comment: @david I will take some more shots tomorrow in better light

Comment: OK so most likely they are none adjustable but possibly lock out I would need to see the top caps on the forks both sides please.

Comment: They may be "adjustable" from the bottom  by putting more tension on the spring but that's not really what is commonly described as adjustable in my experience. Hydraulic forks tend to be lock out or suspension only.  There's no progressive control of adjustment if you get my point. For example unlocked, slightly tougher, slightly tougher, locked. Is progressive "adjustable" control but I think you only find this on air forks. So with hydraulic I think it's just locked or unlocked if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting this morning it turns out they have preload but no lockout.

I will experiment with the preload over the next few days.

This question can be probably be closed now.

Thanks for the assistance in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

These are a spring fork (not such thing as a hydralic sprung fork as discussed in the comments).

Essentially forks fit into two categories - spring is air is a spring. These days the spring is almost always in the left side stanchion. Control of movement - rebound, damping and locking out is provided by hydraulic systems of varying complexity, most commonly in the right side stanchion

With your fork, the right side fork cap (last photo) appears labled 'preload'. This is a very basic adjustment - screwing down the preload tightens the spring making the suspension less compliant.  In basic fork like this you do not tend to have any control of rebound or damping. You may have a lockout level/dial on the top of the left stanchion. Often the lockout is an optional feature - and sometimes able to be retrofitted (if you can find the parts)

Comment: If it has oil or fluid inside it that's hydraulic.

Comment: It relies on fluid and a spring to create damping pressure or you would be riding round on just springs. Nice bouncy ride.

Comment: Although I do generally agree with the most part of your answer.

Comment: @mattnz this doesn't really answer my question or questions at all. Your essentially saying I may have something.

Comment: I cannot tell you if you have lockout, have a look and see if there is a dial on the right. You do have adjustment via the preload.

Comment: I mentioned above if you can show a better pic of the top caps on the fork I can answer your question "do you have lock out" I own two sets of sr suntour forks air and hydraulic both have lock out and it's on the top of the right hand fork stanchion on both. On the top cap. With regard to are your forks adjustable yes you can apply more or less tension to the spring via  either a top cap if you have a adjustable cap (I can tell you with better pics) or via the bolt underneath the fork. Adjustment will be limited in this type of fork and is probably best left alone or adjusted little by little

Comment: Or you may be able to answer part of your own question by looking. Look at the top caps both sides most likely the right hand side though. If you have lock out there will be a lever or switch on the top that has two positions. Open or closed (locked or unlocked) in the unlocked position you will have suspension travel in the locked position the forks will not compress at all. The lever will be easy to spot and operate it will move smoothly and easily. If you can't find this chances are, no lock out. I personally don't know if you could retro  fit to that paticular fork or not maybe you could

Comment: Ask that as a new question if it is the case you don't have lock out and you decide you want it. Although unless you ride on the road a lot or do a lot of really steep climbs I doubt you would find lock out overly use full and would rarely use it imo.

Comment: You may also find it useful to know sr suntour epixon 29er forks are air sprung have lock out or even remote lock out 120mm of travel other options and forks are available.  The reason I mention this one is that they are around 120 which is a cheap upgrade and has all the features you were interested in. If you decide you need those features.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've just got back in after doing a 15 mile trip on the bike in question, I can do more images but after looking at them this morning both left and right caps have preload on them + or -. I've made some adjustments to the positive side but didn't notice much difference to be honest, maybe I need to adjust them more, I'll experiment over the next few days.

Comment: @David, I am doing more road miles for the next few months as training for a Brighton run.

Comment: If you have a look at the forks like I mentioned above you will be able to answer your own question and we can delete all these comments to keep the post clean.

Comment: Or post the images I asked for so I can answer your questions and delete the comments.